# Get intent data from a details fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

The issue I encountered is really interesting for me. I develop an application using the Master Details template. On tablet everything works fine, but when switch to phone here I get something that I am not sure how to approach. After I select an item I launch an intent with the following code:

```
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CategoryDetailActivity.class);
detailIntent.putExtra(CategoryDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
startActivity(detailIntent);
```

and the problem is that I can't get the value of that id from the destination fragment:

```
if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
    _locations = _sqlLoc.getAllLocationsByCategory(getArguments().getInt(ARG_ITEM_ID, -1));
}
else{
    _locations = _sqlLoc.getAllLocationsByCategory(-1);
}
```

With this code I always get -1 instead of the real value. Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you start a new `Activity`? You should just replace your current `Fragment` with the new one if you want to implement the phone version of Master-Details pattern correctly. Something like this: `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, new DetailsFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

You can store any data you need in `Activity` and get it via `(MyActivity)getActivity().getData()` from your fragments. This way you don't need to pass any data via `Bundle` at all.